# Why we do not need to close connections opened to a remote EJB server

Tags: ejb, lookup, remote-server

When I do a JDBC Connection lookup from java, after i am done with it, i am supposed to close the connection.
I wonder how come when we look up a remote EJB, we are still opening some kind of a 'connection' to the EJB remote server. But hey, we never close an EJb remote interface after we are done calling its business methods.

Comment: This sounds more like a rant than a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you're grabbing remote EJB using JNDI. According to JNDI specification, Context has close method.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html

A standard library should implement this close method and use it as shown in below code.

Code snippet from GenericURLContext.java -

```
public Object lookup(String name) throws NamingException {
    ResolveResult res = getRootURLContext(name, myEnv);
    Context ctx = (Context)res.getResolvedObj();
    try {
        return ctx.lookup(res.getRemainingName());
    } finally {
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Reference -

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/jndi/toolkit/url/GenericURLContext.java#GenericURLContext.lookup%28java.lang.String%29